# How would a vampire have a physical love affair

Tags: science-in-society, vampires

There are aplenty vampire questions, however how can I justify a vampire having physical intercourses without requiring anymore "magical" justification or shrugging off any.

Let's imagine a world where vampires are known to humankind, and curious scientists are wondering that Joe the Vampire (pretty common name, but anyone can become a vampire after being bitten) is able to enter into physical intercourse with human female (it seems that the situation is more easily explained for the vampire female to male part), which has been monitored for hard proof that the situation indeed occurs.

Now why this question so many scientists are wondering about: Vampires are dead (big news) medically speaking, as a consequence their hearts are no longer beating, and without any blood being pumped in the below part, it seems completely inconceivable that they may be able to do so without the use of any external tools/toys.

So far, the only explanation I could have would be that they insert something tough in this part, but it cannot explain why so many curious scientists have never caught it.

Comment: Can't the "below part" be animated in the same manner as "upper parts"?

Comment: If you're going to shrug off the fact that medically dead corpses are wandering around like nothing happened you already have your explanation.

Comment: You're going to have to explain how your vampires "work" before a real answer can be provided. As noted by Alexander and sphennings, you've got bodies moving around without blood pumping already. How do their muscles work (or not)? How can a vampire think while medically brain dead? If you can answer those questions, you'll probably have an answer to the question you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

A world in which vampires are known to humankind ...

If we are not talking about this world (Remember, there are some diseases which induce people to want to drink blood, but these are ordinary mortal humans.), we might think up some "finer stuff" to flow in the veins of vampires, and the "finer stuff" makes them immortal.

Why it makes them weak against sunlight is a question to answer. Maybe in your world it doesn't.

And if there is "finer stuff" in their veins, why do they want to drink blood?

Okay, maybe the vampires are actually trying to "help" the humans.

Anyway, the finer stuff is what pumps their muscles, all of them.

But why would such a "vampire" want to have extra-marital sex with humans, if his motivation is to help? Or are these "vampires" properly contracting their marriages?

Answering these kinds of questions might help you build an interesting world that isn't just a re-hash of the currently popular vampire literature.